# Returning a List of type from web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to return a list of some inventory from a web service.  It seems that the web service forces the the list to return as an array.

In the following 3 lines the array portion works, but I can't figure out how to cast it back to a list of type "InventoryToSync"

```
List<InventoryToSync> inventoryList = new List<InventoryToSync>();
Array theArray = myIcsSyncService.ReturnInventoryToSyncDictionary();
inventoryList = myIcsSyncService.ReturnInventoryToSyncDictionary().Cast<InventoryToSync>();
```

Here is my web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(InventoryToSync))]
    public List<InventoryToSync> ReturnInventoryToSyncDictionary()
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

        return inventory.GetInventoryList();
    }
```

I tried to force the type with XmlInclude, but still no go.

How to I force the web service to return a list of my InventoryToSync, or how do I convert the array back to Inventory to Sync.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm about ready to retire it as well ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the "Add Service Reference" dialog, click "Advanced" and choose to use `List<T>` as the collection type.

[image]

Comment: Hi John, could you please clarify the `List<T>` collection type for us? I cant see it.

Comment: It shows as `System.Collections.Generic.List`. Thanks for the awesome edit.